# In the past and now

Tags: vocabulary, idiomatic-language, collocations

is "in the past and now" a commonly used collocation? For example, are titles like these correct: "London in the past and now", "Life in the past and now" etc.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+the+past+and+now%22) currently gives me 184 results---it can be found, but it isn't common.  It's more common to collocate two terms that are grammatically similar to each other, such as:

- Life in the **past** and **present**
- London **yesterday** and **today** (implies a broad meaning of 'yesterday' that can cover past decades)
- London **then** and **now**